# Hibernate entity filters with Spring data repositories

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm attempting to use [Hibernate 4's Entity level `@Filter`'s](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html) with Spring data repositories inside of a Spring Boot project. My end goal is to implement a generic soft delete with something a bit more flexible then Hibernate's `@Where` annotation.

After a bit of a struggle I've come to the possibly naive solution that this could be handled using an `@Aspect`

I set up a Spring managed aspect with the aim to intercept calls to the shared `EntityManager` and enable the appropriate filter.

I played around with a few different pointcuts and it looks like `execution(public * javax.persistence.EntityManager.find(..))` is an ok place to bind this advice.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class HibernateFilterInterceptor {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    private final PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateFilterInterceptor(EntityManager entityManager, PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.platformTransactionManager = platformTransactionManager;
    }

    @Before("execution(public * javax.persistence.EntityManager.find(..))")
    public void beforeFind(){

    }
```

From the Hibernate docs/examples it seems like I should be able to enable the filter using something like `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("filter").setParameter("foo", 1);`

So to test I defined a simple filter on a single entity.

```
@FilterDef(name = "status", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "status", type = "integer"))
@Filters(
    @Filter(name = "status", condition = ":status = status")
)
public class Entity{
```

And enabled it in my advice

```
@Before("execution(public * javax.persistence.EntityManager.find(..))")
public void beforeFind(){
 entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("status").setParameter("status", 1);
}
```

And the filter is not applied.

Comment: are u solve this problem?

Comment: This works https://stackoverflow.com/a/32230857/320761

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to Session using Spring JPA and Hibernate in order to enable filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228031/access-to-session-using-spring-jpa-and-hibernate-in-order-to-enable-filters)